# Flutter web visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I've been using flutter web in visual studio code.
Today I tried upgrading to flutter 1.9.
After that, the option new flutter web project in visual studio is gone.

I tried installing it again, but it doesn't come back.

Are there other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the latest dartcode release. "New Web Project command has been removed. To create web projects, you should now use the standard Flutter: New Project command."

https://dartcode.org/releases/v3-5/